# Error in react-spring with typescript for react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-spring

I'm trying to make an animation using react-spring, but when I go to call the useTransition function passing the properties of some kind of errors I'm not understanding

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTransition } from 'react-spring';
import { Container } from './styles';
import { ToastMessage } from '../../hooks/toast';
import Toast from './Toast/index';

interface ToastContainerProps {
  messages: ToastMessage[];
}

const ToastContainer: React.FC<ToastContainerProps> = ({ messages }) => {
  const messageWithTransitions = useTransition(
    messages,
    message => message.id,
    {
      from: { right: '-120%' },
      enter: { right: '0%' },
      leave: { right: '-120%' },
    },
  );
  return (
    <Container>
      {messageWithTransitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => (
        <Toast key={key} message={item} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ToastContainer;
```

Error:

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(data: OneOrMore, props: () => { ref?: SpringRef<Lookup> | undefined; from?: TransitionFrom; ... 23 more ...; onDestroyed?: ((item: ToastMessage, key: Key) => void) | undefined; } | (object & {}), deps?: any[] | undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(message: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => { ref?: SpringRef<Lookup> | undefined; from?: TransitionFrom; loop?: LoopProp<ControllerUpdate<Lookup, undefined>> | undefined; ... 22 more ...; onDestroyed?: ((item: ToastMessage, key: Key) => void) | undefined; } | (object & {})'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(data: OneOrMore, props: { ref?: SpringRef<Lookup> | undefined; from?: TransitionFrom; ... 23 more ...; onDestroyed?: ((item: ToastMessage, key: Key) => void) | undefined; } | (object & {}), deps: any[] | undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ from: { right: string; }; enter: { right: string; }; leave: { right: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'from' does not exist in type 'any[]'.  TS2769

```
 const ToastContainer: React.FC<ToastContainerProps> = ({ messages }) => {
const messageWithTransitions = useTransition(
                                   ^
     messages,
    message => message.id,
```

Comment: I think you use the old v8 sytax in version 9. In version 9 the useTransition changed. You no longer provide the key for it and also the render part is using render props instead of map.

Comment: Eu usei a versão V8 é funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, since I'm doing the bootcamp too.
I don't know if you've already solved the issue, but I'll paste the solution here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTransition } from 'react-spring';

import Toast from './Toast';

import { ToastMessage } from '../../hooks/toast';
import { Container } from './styles';

interface ToastContainerProps {
  messages: ToastMessage[];
}

const ToastContainer: React.FC<ToastContainerProps> = ({ messages }) => {
  const messagesWithTransitions = useTransition(messages, {
    keys: (message) => message.id,
    from: { right: '-120%' },
    enter: { right: '0%' },
    leave: { right: '-120%' },
  });

  return (
    <Container>
      {messagesWithTransitions((style, item, t) => (
        <Toast key={t.key} style={style} message={item} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ToastContainer;
```

You can read about the changes in `useTransition` hook here, if you want: [Breaking Changes](https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/breaking-changes/)

Comment: Obrigado para resolver rapidamente eu utilizei a versão V8 que não tem essas modificações mas agora vou atualizar para utilizar a nova versão e vou usar sua resposta como base, obrigado pela ajuda amigo!

Comment: Nice! Can you please mark my answer as the solution, in case other people look for it.
PS.: I think you can't speak in another language than English here in stack overflow.